# Laravel : when insert record in table. How can i add that Record in the list without querying the db

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, insert

I have list of customers which show all the customers in a Table

```
public function index(){

     $customers=Customer::all(); 
    return View::make('customer.customer-view')->with('customers',$customers);
```

}

When adding new customer it save in the db.and i want to show the recent added customer in all customer table.  i know i can get it querying the db again is there a good way in Laravel to add the recent added customer obj into customer array without Query

**Store Customer**

```
 public function  store(Request $request){

         $Customer = new Customer;
         $Customer->fill(Request::all());
         if($Customer->save()){
           // Here when it successfully inserted
          }
         return View::make('customer.customer-view'); //route to view all customer


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

1. You should not return a view from a `store` action or anything that is persisting data.

In this you are posting your form data to be saved and then returning a view in a response - this is bad practice.

What you should be doing instead is redirecting back to the index page:

```
public function  store(Request $request){

     $Customer = new Customer;
     $Customer->fill(Request::all());
     if($Customer->save()){
       // Here when it successfully inserted
      }
     return redirect('url/for/index/method'); //route to view all customer
}
```

Or a similar redirect if you use named routes etc.

2. You should really validate the input

How do you know the person filling out the form has provided you with the right information, or even filled it out at all? Going through this is outside the scope of your question, but I would suggest you read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) about this if you want to add it.

3. You aren't ordering your customers

In your current `store` method, you are just returning the same view that you do in your `index` method. You say that you are wanting to return the latest customers.
As such you should look at ordering the results to show the newest first.

Eloquent provides a `latest()` method to help you achieve this.

Additionally, you are currently returning all customers in your `index` method - once you start storing a few customers this could look quite ugly in your view.

Perhaps you want to limit this to say the latest 5, 10, or 15?

To achieve this, you just need to alter you `index` method a little:

```
public function index() {

    $customers = Customer::latest()->take(10)->get(); 
    return View::make('customer.customer-view')->with('customers',$customers);
}
```

All in one go, this is would your controller should look like, and should achieve what you are after:

```
public function index() {

    $customers = Customer::all(); 
    return View::make('customer.customer-view')->with('customers',$customers);
}

public function store(Request $request){

     $Customer = new Customer;
     $Customer->fill(Request::all());
     if($Customer->save()){
       // Here when it successfully inserted
      }
     return redirect('url/for/index/method'); //route to view all customer
}
```

Comment: Great ! Sir  i am using validation just here i didn't show that here to make my question very simple. and i am not that much clear as in Angular i just used to concat the Array but going to the main route then again when hitting customer tab it again going to query.which is not what i want i just want to add the latest customer into customers array.

Comment: @Malik great :) - just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other users,
Your store function should not do anything else but store data.

1. remove the redirect on your store function,
2. yes it is possible to insert newly added record to your list,
   but it is not advisable since you should always validate if the data is acceptable and if it really exists in the db.

I don't think adding 1 line to your store function will slow down the server,

--laravel store function

```
public function  store(Request $request){

         $Customer = new Customer;
         $Customer->fill(Request::all());
         if($Customer->save()){

           // Here when it successfully inserted
           $new_record_id =  $Customer->id();
           $newlyAddedCustomer = Customer::find($new_record_id);

           return $newlyAddedCustomer;

          }else{

           return 'error';
          } 
}
```

--This will refresh your page and your list if your using PHP Form post method,

But if your not using PHP Form, You can do it using jquery and ajax,

--html

```
<ul id='my_list'>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

--ajax

```
$("#buttonSave").on("click", function(){
  var input1 = $("").val(); /* input1 */
  var input2 = $("").val(); /* input2 */
     $.ajax({
        url: 'your laravel route to your store controller',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { input1: input1, input: input2, _token: _token },
        success: function(data){
           if(data!='error'){
             $("#my_list").append("<li>"+data[0].yourfield1+"</li>");
           }
        }
     })
});
```

Comment: the problem here it didnot return the data not to the page where it call from

Comment: i get it now, if you want it to be added on all the tables, you can store it in a variable instead, then loop through that variable to be displayed on your table,